# Solve $(x+2y^3)y'=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$(x+2y^3)y'=y$$

I wonder if my method is correct. This is what I do:
$$(x+2y^3)y'=y\iff(x+2y^3)\frac{dy}{dx}=y\iff(x+2y^3)=y\frac{dx}{dy}\iff(x+2y^3)=yx'\iff x'=\frac{x}{y}+2y^2$$

And this equation is the one I know how to solve. So everything will be fine if my reasoning to this point is correct. Because we started to solve differential equation before relevant theory was given, I do not really know what exactly those $dx,dy$ mean and that's why I am not sure if what I've done is right.

Comment: More simply: $$(y^2)'=2yy'=\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}=\left(\frac{x}y\right)'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following property: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$

So it follows that what you've done is correct, and can now be solved using an integrating factor since the equation can be written as: $\frac{dx}{dy}+P(y)x=Q(y)$

As an aside, here's a proof for the integrating factor $I(y)$:

$I(y)\frac{dx}{dy}+I(y)P(y)x=Q(y)I(y)$

Note that $\frac{d}{dy}(I(y)x)= I(y)\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{d}{dy}(I(y))x$

So if we choose $\frac{d}{dy}I(y)=I(y)P(y)$

Then $\int \frac{1}{I}dI=\int P(y)dy\implies \ln I=\int P(y)dy\implies I = e^{\int P dy}$

Note we can ignore the constant, since it would just cancel out on both sides.

Then we have $\frac{d}{dy}(Iy)=Q(y)I(y)\implies Iy=\int QIdy$

with $I = e^{\int Pdy}$

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote $$x'=\frac{x}{y}+2y^2$$ is very correct. Now, just define $$x=y z\implies x'=yz'+z$$ and replace (last step assuming $y\neq 0$)$$yz'+z=z+2y^2\implies z'=2y\implies z=y^2+C$$ So,$$x=y(y^2+C)=y^3+Cy$$